# finding visible rows in cloned table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find the visible rows inside a cloned table?

```
var divContents = $("#mytable").clone();
divContents.find('tr:visible'); // <-- not working
```

Please **dont** tell me to do this:

```
var divContents = $("#mytable tr:visible").clone();
```

I need to work with the cloned element because I get a copy of it, alter it and then send it to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visible elements can only be detected when the element is part of the DOM. As such you could append the table (well off screen if necessary), work with the visible rows and then remove it (again, if necessary). Something like this:

```
var $divContents = $("#mytable").clone().css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '-10000px'
}).appendTo('body');

var $visibleRows = $divContents.find('tr:visible');
// do something with $visibleRows...

$divContents.remove();
```

Comment: I liked the other answer better, but I ended up using this. thanks.

Comment: `left: '-10000px'` might be a bit narrow with the ever-increasing display resolutions. Rather go `left: '-10000m'` :) That should be future-proof for at least the next two years ;)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `:visible` selector selects elements that consume space in the document.
Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

Your elements aren't even in the document, as they are a cloned set that only exists in memory, so they are by definition not `:visible`, none of them.

If what you really want is to select elements that aren't `display:none` or similar, you can filter based on that

```
var divContents = $("#mytable").clone();

var visible = divContents.find('tr').filter(function(index, elem) {
    return elem.style.display !== 'none' ||
           elem.style.visibility !== 'hidden';
});

visible.css('color', 'red'); // target only visible rows
```

Comment: this seems correct, tho elem is an index, but I fixed it by using this.style.display.... but still after the filter goes thru the rows are still there.

Comment: Fixed the arguments, but not sure what you mean by the elements still being there? `filter` filters the collection, if you want to store the new collection you're going to have to use a variable, as in `var visible = divContents.find('tr').filter(function(index, elem) { ... `